# Why do I get only ".xlsx" instead of full concatenated string

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote this piece of code for set a file name before save to my computer:

```
string name_file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName).Split('.')[0]
                   + blYear.SelectedValue == null ? "2010" : blYear.SelectedValue 
                   + ".xlsx";
```

I trace the code and see the results:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName).Split('.')[0]  "PSIQ DIGITEL"  string
blYear.SelectedValue                                                null            object
name_file                                                           ".xlsx"         string
```

What I'm doing wrong? Why `name_file` lost the original values? Also and with this same question how do I remove spaces between the final file_name lets say like in example "PSIQ DIGITEL" should be "PSIQ-DIGITEL".

**EDIT**

If I remove this part `+ blYear.SelectedValue == null ? "2010" : blYear.SelectedValue` then the file name took the value fine, what's wrong?

Comment: is a ComboBox component

Comment: You should use `Path.Combine` to build your path. `Path.Combine(part1,part2,part3,...)`

Comment: I use Path.Combine later in my code but first need to build the file name

Comment: @Blam: He did, see the "results" in the question.

Comment: put () around the ternary if statement....

Comment: `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName)` will be better than split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Path` class to get the [base file without extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) and then add the desired parts to your file (and remember to isolate the conditional expression from the extension using parenthesys)

```
string base_file = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
string name_file = base_file + 
                   (blYear.SelectedValue == null ? "2010" : blYear.SelectedValue.ToString()) +
                   ".xlsx";
```

Well I think that in this way it is more readable.

By the way, using Split and then get the first element in the resulting array on a file name called `"test.my.file.name.csv"` could not give the intended result

Comment: Excellent, this is I was looking for, I didn't know that method (this are my first steps with C#)

Answer (score 6):

Did you mean this

```
((System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName).Split('.')[0] + blYear.SelectedValue) == null ? "2010" : blYear.SelectedValue) + ".xlsx"
```

or

```
(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName).Split('.')[0] + blYear.SelectedValue) == null ? "2010" : (blYear.SelectedValue + ".xlsx")
```

or

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName).Split('.')[0] + (blYear.SelectedValue == null ? "2010" : blYear.SelectedValue) + ".xlsx"
```

or ?

Use parentheses to tell the compiler what you mean, it pays no attention to linebreaks and indentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use GetFileNameWithoutExtension instead of that split.
And separate the final ".xlsx" isolating the `if` with parentheses.

```
string name_file = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName)
               + (blYear.SelectedValue == null ? "2010" : blYear.SelectedValue) 
               + ".xlsx";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code does:

```
string a = (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName).Split('.')[0]
    + blYear.SelectedValue) == null ? "2010" : blYear.SelectedValue; 
string name_file = a + ".xlsx";
```

So that if the filename is filled at all, you'll use the selected value blYear, which might be empty. Hint: always use parenthesis when using the `?` operator with string concatenations. It'll keep you sane.

Also, use the `Replace` method to change spaces into minuses. Like this:

```
name_file = name_file.Replace(" ", "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should break your expression down into three separate statements and trace through them in the MSVS debugger:

```
  String nameFile;
  nameFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName).Split('.')[0];
  nameFile += blYear.SelectedValue == null ? "2010" : blYear.SelectedValue;
  nameFile += ".xlsx";
```

... or, better ...

```
  String nameFile;
  nameFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
  nameFile = nameFile.Split('.')[0];
  nameFile += ((blYear.SelectedValue == null) ? "2010" : blYear.SelectedValue);
  nameFile += ".xlsx";
```

Running everything together gives you *no* performance benefits, and makes troubelshooting tricky.

I suspect you'll find that *neither* GetFileName(...).Split() or blYear.SelectedValue are what you think they should be.

IMHO...